# Undefined struct timeval declaration in C

Tags: c, struct, mpi, declaration

I have a code below

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include "mpi.h"
#define NRA 512    /* number of rows in matrix A */
#define NCA 512   /* number of columns in matrix A */
#define NCB 512         /* number of columns in matrix B */
#define MASTER 0      /* taskid of first task */
#define FROM_MASTER 1  /* setting a message type */
#define FROM_WORKER 2  /* setting a message type */

MPI_Status status;

double a[NRA][NCA],   /* matrix A to be multiplied */
     b[NCA][NCB],       /* matrix B to be multiplied */
     c[NRA][NCB];      /* result matrix C */

main(int argc, char **argv)
{
int numtasks,   /* number of tasks in partition */
  taskid,       /* a task identifier */
  numworkers,   /* number of worker tasks */
  source,       /* task id of message source */
  dest,        /* task id of message destination */
  nbytes,         /* number of bytes in message */
  mtype,          /* message type */
  intsize,   /* size of an integer in bytes */
  dbsize,       /* size of a double float in bytes */
  rows,                       /* rows of matrix A sent to each worker */
  averow, extra, offset,      /* used to determine rows sent to each worker */
  i, j, k,   /* misc */
  count;

struct timeval start, stop;

intsize = sizeof(int);
dbsize = sizeof(double);

MPI_Init(&argc, &argv);
MPI_Comm_rank(MPI_COMM_WORLD, &taskid);
MPI_Comm_size(MPI_COMM_WORLD, &numtasks);
numworkers = numtasks-1;

//printf("   size of matrix A = %d by %d\n",NRA,NCA);
//printf("   size of matrix B = %d by %d\n",NRA,NCB);
/*---------------------------- master ----------------------------*/
if (taskid == MASTER) {
printf("Number of worker tasks = %d\n",numworkers);
for (i=0; i<NRA; i++)
  for (j=0; j<NCA; j++)
    a[i][j]= i+j;
for (i=0; i<NCA; i++)
  for (j=0; j<NCB; j++)
    b[i][j]= i*j;

gettimeofday(&start, 0);

/* send matrix data to the worker tasks */
averow = NRA/numworkers;
extra = NRA%numworkers;
offset = 0;
mtype = FROM_MASTER;
for (dest=1; dest<=numworkers; dest++) { 
  rows = (dest <= extra) ? averow+1 : averow;  
  //printf("   Sending %d rows to task %d\n",rows,dest);
  MPI_Send(&offset, 1, MPI_INT, dest, mtype, MPI_COMM_WORLD);
  MPI_Send(&rows, 1, MPI_INT, dest, mtype, MPI_COMM_WORLD);
  count = rows*NCA;
  MPI_Send(&a[offset][0], count, MPI_DOUBLE, dest, mtype, MPI_COMM_WORLD);
  count = NCA*NCB;
  MPI_Send(&b, count, MPI_DOUBLE, dest, mtype, MPI_COMM_WORLD);

  offset = offset + rows;
  }

/* wait for results from all worker tasks */
mtype = FROM_WORKER;
for (i=1; i<=numworkers; i++) { 
  source = i;
  MPI_Recv(&offset, 1, MPI_INT, source, mtype, MPI_COMM_WORLD, &status);
  MPI_Recv(&rows, 1, MPI_INT, source, mtype, MPI_COMM_WORLD, &status);
  count = rows*NCB;
  MPI_Recv(&c[offset][0], count, MPI_DOUBLE, source, mtype, MPI_COMM_WORLD,
             &status);

  }

#ifdef PRINT
printf("Here is the result matrix\n");
for (i=0; i<NRA; i++) {
  printf("\n");
  for (j=0; j<NCB; j++)
    printf("%6.2f   ", c[i][j]);
  }
printf ("\n");
#endif

gettimeofday(&stop, 0);


fprintf(stdout,"Time = %.6f\n\n",
       (stop.tv_sec+stop.tv_usec*1e-6)-(start.tv_sec+start.tv_usec*1e-6));

}  /* end of master section */

/*---------------------------- worker (slave)----------------------------*/
if (taskid > MASTER) {
mtype = FROM_MASTER;
source = MASTER;
#ifdef PRINT
printf ("Master =%d, mtype=%d\n", source, mtype);
#endif
MPI_Recv(&offset, 1, MPI_INT, source, mtype, MPI_COMM_WORLD, &status);
#ifdef PRINT
printf ("offset =%d\n", offset);
#endif
MPI_Recv(&rows, 1, MPI_INT, source, mtype, MPI_COMM_WORLD, &status);
#ifdef PRINT
printf ("row =%d\n", rows);
#endif
count = rows*NCA;
MPI_Recv(&a, count, MPI_DOUBLE, source, mtype, MPI_COMM_WORLD, &status);
#ifdef PRINT
printf ("a[0][0] =%e\n", a[0][0]);
#endif
count = NCA*NCB;
MPI_Recv(&b, count, MPI_DOUBLE, source, mtype, MPI_COMM_WORLD, &status);
#ifdef PRINT
printf ("b=\n");
#endif
for (k=0; k<NCB; k++)
  for (i=0; i<rows; i++) {
    c[i][k] = 0.0;
    for (j=0; j<NCA; j++)
      c[i][k] = c[i][k] + a[i][j] * b[j][k];
    }

//mtype = FROM_WORKER;
#ifdef PRINT
printf ("after computer\n");
#endif
//MPI_Send(&offset, 1, MPI_INT, MASTER, mtype, MPI_COMM_WORLD);
MPI_Send(&offset, 1, MPI_INT, MASTER, FROM_WORKER, MPI_COMM_WORLD);
//MPI_Send(&rows, 1, MPI_INT, MASTER, mtype, MPI_COMM_WORLD);
MPI_Send(&rows, 1, MPI_INT, MASTER, FROM_WORKER, MPI_COMM_WORLD);
//MPI_Send(&c, rows*NCB, MPI_DOUBLE, MASTER, mtype, MPI_COMM_WORLD);
MPI_Send(&c, rows*NCB, MPI_DOUBLE, MASTER, FROM_WORKER, MPI_COMM_WORLD);
#ifdef PRINT
printf ("after send\n");
#endif
}  /* end of worker */

MPI_Finalize();
} /* end of main */
```

when i try to compile it, the warning was :

> matriks.c(43): error C2079: 'start' uses undefined struct 'timeval'
>   matriks.c(43): error C2079: 'stop' uses undefined struct 'timeval'
>   matriks.c(65): warning C4013: 'gettimeofday' undefined; assuming extern returning int
>   matriks.c(111): error C2224: left of '.tv_sec' must have struct/union type
>   matriks.c(111): error C2224: left of '.tv_usec' must have struct/union type
>   matriks.c(111): error C2224: left of '.tv_sec' must have struct/union type
>   matriks.c(111): error C2224: left of '.tv_usec' must have struct/union type

Please help, I don't know where the error is. Thank you.

Comment: Why not use `MPI_Wtime()` to measure the time? It is supposed to use the highest resolution timer available to the system. Just call it twice and subtract the values to obtain a `double` value of the number of seconds passed between the invocations.

Comment: Do you have an example of `MPI_Wtime()` usage? Thanks before

Comment: `double tstart = MPI_Wtime(); ...; double tend = MPI_Wtime(); printf("Time passed: %f seconds\n", tend - tstart);`

Comment: I forgot to mention that `MPI_Wtime()` belongs to the few exceptions in the MPI API that can be called before `MPI_Init()` and after `MPI_Finalize()`.

Answer (score 3):

I think you'll probably find that `timeval` needs you to include `sys/time.h` under POSIX systems (it's not standard C). See [the POSIX SUSv2](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/7908799/xsh/systime.h.html) page for details.

Comment: The problem is, `sys/time.h` isn't include in the Visual Studio 2010. When I try to search it independently, I found it but it needs another header in it. :(

Comment: You should have specified the platform, @sintakartika, there's nothing in the question to indicate that it's anything other than UNIX-style C. I believe timeval under Windows is part of Winsock since it's needed by the `select` call. So probably in winsock2.h although I haven't checked in detail.